# Move and set the value of a XYChart.Data node in line chart

Tags: java, javafx

I want to have an interactive line chart that allows me to move and *set* the underlying value of points on the chart. Adding a mouse event ondragged handler to the nodes of the XYChart.Data points should allow me to do this, but I need to be able to translate the mouse event position into the axis frame of reference of the point. Using the following;

```
xAxis.getValueForDisplay(event.getX()).doubleValue();
```

where xAxis is the number axis of the line chart does not work on the mouse events applied to the XYChart.Data points (it does when you use this approach on the node of the chart background). Below is my code;

```
package com.jtech;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MovePoint extends Application {

    class MouseHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
        private XYChart.Data data;
        private Axis<Number> xAxis, yAxis;

        public MouseHandler(XYChart.Data data, Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis) {
            this.data=data;
            this.xAxis=xAxis;
            this.yAxis=yAxis;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            //we want these in the axis coordinate frame
            double x =  xAxis.getValueForDisplay(event.getX()).doubleValue();
            double y =  yAxis.getValueForDisplay(event.getY()).doubleValue();

            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                System.out.println(String.format("(%.2f,%.2f)",x,y));
                //data.setXValue(x);
                //data.setYValue(y);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,6,1);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0,10,2);

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Point moving example");
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        final XYChart.Data d1 = new XYChart.Data(0.0, 0.0);
        final XYChart.Data d2 = new XYChart.Data(0.5, 2.0);
        final XYChart.Data d3 = new XYChart.Data(2.0, 2.5);
        final XYChart.Data d4 = new XYChart.Data(3.5, 3.5);
        final XYChart.Data d5 = new XYChart.Data(5.0, 8.0);

        series.getData().addAll(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        registerNode(d1,xAxis, yAxis);
        registerNode(d2,xAxis, yAxis);
        registerNode(d3,xAxis, yAxis);
        registerNode(d4,xAxis, yAxis);
        registerNode(d5,xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    private void registerNode(XYChart.Data data, Axis<Number> xAxis, Axis<Number> yAxis) {
        final Node node = data.getNode();
        node.setOnMouseDragged(new MouseHandler(data,xAxis,yAxis));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What would be the correct approach to achieving this? I've seen some examples that translate the actual node, but I was curious to know if I could do it by setting the actual X,Y values of the data directly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375922/javafx-how-to-correctly-implement-getvaluefordisplay-on-y-axis-of-a-xy-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems perfectly possible:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DraggingLineChartSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 12, 1);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 50, 5);
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = 
                new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");

        lineChart.setAnimated(false);

        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(12, 25));        

        Scene scene  = new Scene(new BorderPane(lineChart),800,600);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        for (Data<Number, Number> data : series.getData()) {
            Node node = data.getNode() ;
            node.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            node.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
                Point2D pointInScene = new Point2D(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY());
                double xAxisLoc = xAxis.sceneToLocal(pointInScene).getX();
                double yAxisLoc = yAxis.sceneToLocal(pointInScene).getY();
                Number x = xAxis.getValueForDisplay(xAxisLoc);
                Number y = yAxis.getValueForDisplay(yAxisLoc);
                data.setXValue(x);
                data.setYValue(y);
            });
        }


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I am tied into Java 7, but using the sceneToLocal and getValueForDisplay approach solved this for me.